# Why is my server shows different timestamp for utc and current timestamp if the timezone is +00:00?

Tags: mysql, timestamp-with-timezone

while doing research i was curious why my server shows different timestamp when i execute below query?

```
select current_timestamp(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), convert_tz(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 
@@session.time_zone,"+00:00") as timezone_utc, 
convert_tz(current_timestamp(), @@session.time_zone,"+00:00") as timezone_current
```

OUTPUT :

```
current_timestamp() || UTC_TIMESTAMP() || timezone_utc || timezone_current

2015-04-02 03:01:25 || 2015-04-02 08:01:25 || 2015-04-02 13:01:25 || 2015-04-02 08:01:25
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're confused as to why the third column (timezone_utc) doesn't show the same result as the first column (current_timestamp()), it's because you have the "from" and "to" arguments to CONVERT_TZ() the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you told it to, and it believes what you tell it. `convert_tz(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 
@@session.time_zone,"+00:00")` says to take the current UTC time, pretend it's actually local time, and then convert it to UTC by adding the opposite of the local timezone offset. This is a nonsensical thing to do and gets a nonsensical result.